# Proxying HTTP requests in a particular way / how to avoid handshake and proxy the rest?

Tags: node.js, http, https, proxy, http-proxy

I want to setup an HTTP proxy server that works in a particular way. I only proxy requests to website X: for each request the proxy server will try to fulfill it using a list of standard HTTP proxies until I get an acceptable request (an acceptable request in my use case is one with a non 403 HTTP status, because X has a high chance to respond with 403 and bans the IP).

I tried difference techniques, the straightforward way I took is to use the `net` package of nodejs: create a socket server, listen for traffic and do the proxying. The difficulty I am facing is with HTTPs handshake, I could for example forward the client socket to an X socket and X to client for the handshake (CONNECT) and respond to the rest (the POST/GET requests) by doing my work. The problem is that I don't see how to re-use the socket that initiated the handshake which should be necessary, there should be some encryption happening that I can't achieve (I guess) because the server uses it's private key to generate the data.

**My question is whether this scenario is feasible: set a proxy server to catch GET and POST requests, execute them in some way (using another client), then return the answer to the client (a browser for instance) without having this latter complaining about HTTPS error and without putting a custom certificate into the client.**

**Or, is there any other way to achieve the end goal: proxy a request in the browser using a set of proxies until I get the desired HTTP response? the end-user should only see the desired response.**